# Twig templates directory

Tags: twig

I'm new to Twig and was wondering where I should place the Twig /templates directory.

I'm using **composer** and placing the /templates in the root directory where the index.php is and it gives me the following error message :

```
Message: The "/templates" directory does not exist.
File:   /home/teo/SERVER/public_html/JSON_FOLDER/JSON2/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you put it anywhere not within your web root, that's the best practice. But if you have no access anywhere else, then the web root will have to do.

I'm not completely familiar with composer, but you'll probably want to specify a path that is relative to your web directory instead of an absolute directory like you've done already. That error shows that its trying to find a templates path in your server ROOT directory which is almost never going to be where you actually want it. Try just removing the leading slash in your config.